# get image with picasso based on userId firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to do the image upload and download for a user profile, when I save a photo I save it with the userId so I can replace it everytime he changes his photo, now what I need is to get that photo with picasso, the thing is, I don't know how to get the photo, it can have different formats and other stuffs like jpeg, png, I just want to get the image when the userID match, I tried this:

```
storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://friendlymanager-3b7a2.appspot.com");

Picasso.with(UserSettings.this).load(storageRef + "/Photos/" + userId).into(userImage);
```

my userImage is my imageView, i don't get any erros just a blank image, i already have a photo for the specific user.

Any help?

Comment: Does your link return a image?

Comment: how can i check that?

Comment: Log your final url. `Log.d("URL", storageRef + "/Photos/" + userId);`

Comment: tried with .jpg at final and without and i get a plain string: 04-13 11:28:14.227 28459-28459/com.esmad.pdm.friendlymanager D/image2: gs://friendlymanager-3b7a2.appspot.com/Photos/LqZ5YSxHQZY7JKta5EGWiL3MXi93.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using [Firebase-UI Android library](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android) which gives you ability to load images from storage ref directly. In your case it would look something like this

I'm not sure if Picasso is supported but you can use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)
 for example:

```
mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

Glide.with(this /* context */)
    .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
    .load(mStorageRef + "/Photos/" + userId)
    .error(R.drawable.default)
    .into(imageView);
```

Comment: seems fine, but do i need to know the image format right?(jpeg,png)?

Comment: No Glide will handle all of that fancy stuff for you, also caching as well

Comment: seems nice, i will test it, i give you feedback soon

Comment: what is the firebaseImageLoader? cant find it

Comment: Its part of Firebase-UI Android library add  compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.2.0' to your dependencies and sync the project

For more details visit the link from the answer

Comment: can't upgrade the gradle dependency i get an error on my 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0', saying something about twitter sdk :S

Answer (score 3):

you will have to get download link like this,

```
 StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReference().child("users").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());//reach out to your photo file hierarchically as stored  on firebase
            storageRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                    Log.e("URI", uri.toString());
                    Glide.with(SaveUserActivity.this).load(uri).into(profile_image);
                    url = uri.toString();

                }
            });
```

Comment: where do i pass the uri?

Comment: i've used glide to load image, picasso alaso has method to load image using Uri.
somthing like this Picasso.with(context).load(uri).into(imageView);

Answer (score 2):

You should use `getDownloadUrl()` while fetching images from Firebase storage using Picasso OR glide etc.